# two .then in axios

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am trying to load the Ag-grid. I saw this code sample, but I don’t know why they use two times `.then`. Can anyone help me to understand it?
Thank you

```
beforeMount() {
    this.columnDefs = [
        {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make'},
        {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model'},
        {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'}
    ];

    fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9')
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(rowData => this.rowData = rowData);
}
```

Comment: Do you provide an initial `rowData` in the `data` function of your component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `response.json()` call itself returns another Promise, as you can read up [in the documentation about `Body.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json). The reason for that is that response body contains a stream that needs to get parsed and converted into JS data structures before you can use it.